# Cannot create a web application project, getting INVALID_TOS error

Tags: google-app-engine

Having issue in creating a new web application project with Google App Engine plug-in for Eclipse (GAE for Java version 1.9.0). I keep getting error

> INVALID_TOS: User must accept most recent ToS

when trying to create App Id field. The New Web Application Wizard wont let me type in App Id or leave it blank. Finish button stays disabled.

Cannot find how to accept Googles terms of service. What's triggering this error?

Comment: I get this problem too after upgrading to 1.9.0. My existing projects load and deploy without error. Just unable to create new projects base on existing app id.

Comment: You should try to go there: https://console.developers.google.com/project I think I had to accept new TOS this week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to: https://console.developers.google.com/accountsettings

And accept the TOS shown in pop-up, you are good to go.